# Is there FIB Plus Component Available for Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe5, fibplus

In my current project Delphi  2010 with Firebird latest version used. Also used FIB Plus 7 to connect to firebird.

There is a plan to go for Delphi XE5.

Any suggestions whether support for Delphi XE5 with FIB Plus available or any good alternatives available along with conversion to from FIB plus components ?

Thanks In Advance.

With Best Regards.

Vishal

Comment: Since the company has not updated it's site since XE5 and we are now 4 version later, I would think they are not planning updating it.    If you have the source you could do it.

Comment: Interbase Express is an alternative that ships with the product http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Getting_Started_with_InterBase_Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile it and use FIB+ in XE5 but you won't be able to use the designers etc. in the IDE.  For example you will just get a memo box to enter SQL instead of the fancy form that the designers provide.  To get it working you just need to create new packages for XE5 which are pretty much the same as the XE4.  I just copied the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Devrace\FIBPlus 7.5\sources\D_XE4" on my PC to and edited FIBPlus.inc to inculde:

```
// Delphi XE5
{$IFDEF VER260}
  {$DEFINE D_XE5}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF D_XE5}
  {$DEFINE D_XE4}
{$ENDIF}
```

But really the product is all but dead now and it would be best to think about using something else. We have moved to FireDac but some customers had lots of fast reports using FIB+ and it was easier to compile in the FIB+ just for their reports than do them all again as a stop gap.